# Intent of the code with binary bitwise and shift operators, finding minimal version

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

I am trying to understand this code. It seem like trying to identify version but intent is not clear to me. Why us bit shifting is involved? And why `0x3F`?

```cs
MinimumVersion = (version.Build & 0x7FFF) |
                 ((version.Minor & 0x3F) << 16) |
                 ((version.Major & 0x3F) << 22) |
                 0x70008000;
```

When I substitute variables with version parts, I get `1941995520`. How does this construct works?

I did this

```cs
Console.WriteLine(0 & 0x7FFF);
Console.WriteLine((0 & 0x3F) << 16);
Console.WriteLine((15 & 0x3F) << 22);
Console.WriteLine(0x70008000);
```

Return is

```
0
0
62914560
1879080960
```

Sum of these is in fact `1941995520`

Comment: Working on an answer I see what is trying to be done but it looks wrong.  Where was this code?

Comment: @Hogan Microsoft open source. Thank you.  Updated question too

Comment: `|` (bitwise or) is not always the same as sum -- but it is here because the bit fields are shifted to not be in the digit.

Comment: @Hogan I am trying to understand it more completely. Why `0x3F` , why `22`, why `16`, why `0x70008000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand this you need to understand what I would call bit field manipulation.  I'll start with the basics to make it clear

```
 x & y
```

This is a bitwise and.   This means if a bit is set in the source and destination it will be set in the result.  This code is using a mask

```
 x & 0x3F
```

remember the bit representation of 0x3F is 6 bits (0011 1111) so this is taking the bottom 6  binary (bit) digits and keeping those but removing everything else.  You are left with a number that fits in 6 binary digits.

---

```
 a | b
```

This is a bitwise or.  This means if a bit is set in either operand it will be set in the output.

You can think of this as a concatenation if there is no "overlap" of bits.

---

Here is an example, I will be using smaller numbers (and smaller bit fields) -- remember  1111 (4 bits) is equal to 15 or 0x0F

So lets say we had

```
x = 3 and y = 5 or (0x03 and 0x05)
```

If we did

```
(x & 0x0F)  << 4 | (y & 0x0F)
```

This would give us 0x35

We are storing 2 4 bit values in 8 bits.
We are also making sure x and y fit in 4 bits

---

The code you are showing is doing something similar but with different sized bit fields.

```
(version.Build & 0x7FFF) |
((version.Minor & 0x3F) << 16) |
((version.Major & 0x3F) << 22) |
 0x70008000;
```

This says

put the value in version.Build in the bottom 15 bitss

put the value of version.Minor in the 22st - 17th bits

put the value of version.Major in the 28th - 23nd bits

set the bits located at 0b1110000000000001000000000000000 to true.

So you end up with a number that gets bigger as version number gets bigger and fits in a long

Comment: So, you are saying that this has been done to avoid writing some complex version comparison code, and instead it is just works on the level of positioning bits in certain order, which in the end will get you a number to compare, yes?

Comment: When you said *"0x3F is 6 bits (0011 1111)"* , do you calculate in your head or use a tool or formula?

Comment: @T.S. I calculated in my head -- sort of.  I think I put the four 1s for the F and then the 0011 for 3.  Program in ASM for a couple of years and you will get it :)

Comment: @T.S. -- I can't say why they are doing this -- I think it is just an easy way to "pack" the values into a smaller space.  Why is that good?  Depends on the rest of the application and the design.

Comment: Cool. I used this binary calc https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/decimal-to-binary.html